# Compute $ \lim_{x \to\frac{\pi} {2}} \{1^{\sec^2 x} + 2^{\sec^2 x} + \cdots + n^{\sec^2 x}\}^{\cos^2 x} $

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to\frac{\pi} {2}} \{1^{\sec^2 x} + 2^{\sec^2 x} + \cdots + n^{\sec^2 x}\}^{\cos^2 x} $
I tried to do like this :
Let $A=\displaystyle \lim_{x \to\frac{\pi}{2}} \{1^{\sec^2 x} + 2^{\sec^2 x} + \cdots + n^{\sec^2 x}\}^{\cos^2 x} $

Then $\ln A=\lim_{x \to\frac{\pi} {2}} \cos^2 x \ln\{1^{\sec^2 x} + 2^{\sec^2 x} + \cdots + n^{\sec^2 x}\}$
which implies
$$\ln A = \lim_{x \to\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac{1^{\sec^2 x} + 2^{\sec^2 x}+ \cdots + n^{\sec^2 x}}{\sec^2 x}$$
I'm stuck here. If I am on the right way please guide me to reach conclusion. Otherwise please describe the actual way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)$ be the sequence given by

$$f_n(x)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{\sec^2(x)}\right)^{\cos^2(x)}$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
f_n(x)&=\left(n^{\sec^2(x)}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac kn\right)^{\sec^2(x)}\right)^{\cos^2(x)}\\\\
&=n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac kn\right)^{\sec^2(x)}\right)^{\cos^2(x)}\\\\
\end{align}$$

For any fixed $n\ge1$

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}(k/n)^{\sec^2(x)}=\begin{cases}0&1\le k<n\\\\1&,k=n\end{cases}$$

Therefore, we have

$$\lim_{x\to \pi/2}f_n(x)=n$$

Comment: No Sir I can't. Can you please describe me?

Comment: Sure.  I've edited  to provide a clear way forward.

Comment: Nice explanation.

Comment: Thank you.  Much appreciate your feedback.  And pleased this was useful.

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\sec(x) = 1/\cos(x)$
and
$\cos(\pi/2+y)
=\cos(\pi/2)\cos(y)-\sin(\pi/2)\sin(y)
=-\sin(y)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
a(n)
&=\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{\sec^2(x)}\right)^{\cos^2(x)}\\
&=\lim_{y \to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{\sec^2(y+\pi/2)}\right)^{\cos^2(y+\pi/2)}\\
&=\lim_{y \to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/\sin^2(y)}\right)^{\sin^2(y)}\\
&=\lim_{z \to 0}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/z}\right)^{z}
\qquad z = \sin^2(y)\\
&=\lim_{w \to \infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{w}\right)^{1/w}
\qquad w = 1/z\\
&=\lim_{w \to \infty}\left(n^w\sum_{k=1}^n (k/n)^{w}\right)^{1/w}\\
&=\lim_{w \to \infty}n\left(\sum_{k=1}^n (k/n)^{w}\right)^{1/w}\\
&=\lim_{w \to \infty}n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ((n-k)/n)^{w}\right)^{1/w}\\
&=\lim_{w \to \infty}n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (1-k/n)^{w}\right)^{1/w}\\
&=\lim_{w \to \infty}n\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-k/n)^{w}\right)^{1/w}\\
&\ge n\\
\text{and}\\
a(n)
&=\lim_{w \to \infty}n\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (1-k/n)^{w}\right)^{1/w}\\
&\le\lim_{w \to \infty}n\left(1+n-1\right)^{1/w}\\
&=\lim_{w \to \infty}nn^{1/w}\\
&\to n\\
\end{array}
$

so the limit is $n$.

Comment: Hi Marty.  I hope that you are doing well and staying safe and healthy.   Wow, that is a lot of work.  ;-))

Comment: I never write anything down. I just enter the mathjax (either in the answer box or macdown) and see where it goes. So what you see is all my work.

Comment: And I'm doing ok.

Comment: Pleased to hear!

Comment: Sir I am unable to understand the last inequality you considered to apply Sandwich theorem. Can you please spare some valuable time of yours to help me understand this.

Comment: First, $(1-k/n)^w < 1$; second, $n^{1/w} \to 1$ as $w \to \infty$.

Comment: @martycohen Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffd]{\lim_{x \to \pi/2}\bracks{\large1^{\sec^{2}\pars{x}} + 2^{\sec^{2}\pars{x}} +
\cdots + n^{\sec^{2}\pars{x}}}^{\large\cos^{2}\pars{x}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{x \to \infty}\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{x}}^{1/x} =
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to \infty}{\ln\pars{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{x}} \over x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to \infty}{\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{x}\ln\pars{k} \over
\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^{x}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\exp\pars{\lim_{x \to \infty}
{\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\pars{k/n}^{x}\ln\pars{k} + \ln\pars{n} \over
\sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1}\pars{k/n}^{x} + 1}} =
\expo{\ln\pars{n}} =
\bbox[15px,#ffd,border:1px solid navy]{n}
\end{align}